# What is the difference between dependencies and dev-dependencies in Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, cargo, toml

My question is `What is the difference between dependencies and dev-dependencies in Cargo.toml`. And for developing pallet, now I have to declare crate in `dependencies`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general Rust concept:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/dev_dependencies.html

Basically, `[dev-dependencies]` are the crates you only need for compiling and running tests.

There are at least two advantages of separating test crates in this way:

1. When compiling for release, these test crates are not compiled into your binary, which can save space and compilation time.
2. Normally, the Rust compiler checks for and prohibits any [cyclic dependencies](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-resolve-cyclic-dependency/51387). For `[dev-dependencies]`, this check is ignored, allowing two crates to be dependent on eachother specifically for tests.

If you use a crate in your main code, you must include it as a `[dependencies]`, however, if you only use it for tests, then you should place it as a `[dev-dependencies]`.

If you are confused, I recommend to copy patterns from other crates found in Substrate.

Comment: Thank you, good stuff!

Comment: What if you only want to use it for benchmarking and testing?

Comment: You make the dependency "optional" and then enable the dependency when `runtime-benchmarks` feature flag is enabled